# Adding Background messes Layout_Weight

Tags: android, layout

This is the Upper Layout. And here I'm simply using a HTML color as the background.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutUpper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ..........
    ..........

</LinearLayout>
```

Now if I change the background to a drawable my layout get's messed up.

```
        android:background="@drawable/dark"
```

The HTML Color Code layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbzQY.png
The Drawable layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrcxQ.png

Comment: What is @drawable/dark? Image or XML?

Comment: An image, named Dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

When you placed the image as your background, it will display the entirety of the image (hence "wrapping the content")

To prevent this, you can change the height to a certain, fixed value...for example:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

50dp kills the layout_gravity attribute.

Comment: If the parent LinearLayout orientation is vertical, layout_height should be 0dp because layout_weight is the relevant attribute for height.